# Error occured while updating field in database: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Unknown Module.in mvc

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table with columns checkbox,Document name,Field & so on. In Field column I have displayed dropdown so as I change the values in dropdown it should be updated in table.I am passing DocumentId and  crossponding fieldId (of row)through jquery to controller.**But I get this error in Repository.cs file
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Unknown Module.**

**This is my Controller Code**

```
       public ActionResult FieldSubmitted(long VendorId, int DocumentId, int FieldId)                                              
  {
         SubmittedDocument submittedDocument = new SubmittedDocument();

  var requestedDocument = _requestedDocumentService.GetVendorDocuments(VendorId).Where(t => t.DocumentID == DocumentId).FirstOrDefault();

 if (requestedDocument != null)
 {
     submittedDocument = _submittedDocumentService.GetVendorDocuments(VendorId).Where(t => t.RequestedDocumentID == requestedDocument.RequestedDocumentID).FirstOrDefault();
     submittedDocument.FieldId = FieldId;
     _submittedDocumentService.UpdateSubmittedDocument(submittedDocument);

 }

 return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**My Service**

```
       public int UpdateSubmittedDocument(SubmittedDocument submittedDocument)
    {
       int a= _submittedDocumentRepository.Update(submittedDocument, submittedDocument.SubmittedDocumentID);
       return a;
    }
```

**Repository.cs**

```
            public class Repository<TObject> : IRepository<TObject>

           public virtual void UpdateAuditedEntries(object obj)
    {
        if (CurrentUser == null)
            return;
        if (obj == null)
            return;
        var auditedEntity = obj as IAuditedEntity;
        if (auditedEntity != null)
        {
            auditedEntity.ModifiedBy = CurrentUser.UserId;
            auditedEntity.ModifiedDateTime = DateTime.Now;

            obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(x =>
                {
                    var child = x.GetValue(obj);
                    UpdateAuditedEntries(child);
                });
        }
        else
        {
            var propertyCollection = obj as ICollection;
            if (propertyCollection != null)
            {
                foreach (object child in propertyCollection)
                {
                    UpdateAuditedEntries(child);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**I am getting error at var child = x.GetValue(obj);** this line 
**An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Unknown Module.**

Comment: Do you get a full stack trace? If so, that should help a lot.

Comment: You are calling UpdateAuditedEntries(child); recursively within your function. I suspect that is causing the stackoverflow exception.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `UpdateAuditedEntries(child)`; recursively within your function and it does not end. I suspect that is causing the stackoverflow exception